# Alignment of checkbox in a row

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes in a row. I want to keep distance between them. I have tried padding attribute. It is not working though. I am attaching the screenshot

[image]
Here's my code -

```html
<div class="row">
  <label class="cd-admin-create-patient-label">Role </label>
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.super" value="Super" />Super
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.power" value="Power" />Power
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.regular" value="Regular" />Regular
</div>
```

Comment: Check The ans :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[name=role]{
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label class="cd-admin-create-patient-label">Role </label>
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.super" value="Super" />Super
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.power" value="Power" />Power
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.regular" value="Regular" />Regular
</div>
```

Try to use `margin`

Comment: How do I give spacing between label and checkbox?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. px doesn't make the UI responsive right? If yes, is there any alternative?

Comment: @chan Do you want to make responsive web? So, do you want to make this without `px`?

Comment: @chan There are many way to solve. I suggest to use `vw` or `vh`. If you don't know about that please search this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.role {
margin-right:25px; /* you can here Give margin for label*/
}

.boxes{

margin-right:55px; /* you Can here Give margin for chekboxes */

}
```

```html
<div class = "row">

<label class="cd-admin-create-patient-label role">Role: </label>

<span class="boxes">
<input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.super" value="Super"/>Super
</span>       
         
<span class="boxes">
<input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.power" value="Power"/>Power </span>
                  
<span class="boxes">
<input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.regular" value="Regular" />Regular
</span>        


</div>
```

Comment: px doesn't make the UI responsive right? If yes, is there any alternative?

Comment: Seems like it would semantically be more correct to use labels, rather than spans.

Comment: @chan Define "responsive"? Would there be a reason you'd want the space between to depend on the screen resolution?

Comment: @chan you can use the bootstrap for it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use padding for this, use left margin to your checkboxes. I have used `margin-left: 10vw` for margin-left which will calculate the margin according to your viewport.

```css
.row>input[type="checkbox"]{
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label class="cd-admin-create-patient-label">Role </label>
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.super" value="Super" />Super
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.power" value="Power" />Power
  <input class="roleCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="role" ng-model="user.regular" value="Regular" />Regular
</div>
```

Comment: what about spacing between label and checbox?

Comment: Currently you are not using labels for inputs, attach a label for your input using an id and name. Put the spacing for your labels too, as I did for input. Hope that helps.